# How to set valueForKey in UIActionSheet for buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I am totally revamp one of the old project ,and in that they using `UIActionSheet` ,i am not familiar with it so please help me to find out .

```
UIActionSheet *popupQuery = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"beard Selection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"   destructiveButtonTitle:@""   otherButtonTitles:@"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];

    NSLog(@"kishore calculation ");
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:1] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:2] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:3] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:4] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:5] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca6.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:6] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca7.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:7] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca8.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:8] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca9.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[[popupQuery valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:9] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ca10.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    popupQuery.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
    [popupQuery setTag:Cap];
    [popupQuery showInView:self.view];
```

`UIActionSheet` is like a `UIAlertView` ,in that they tried to add buttons but i am getting error like this ,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key buttons.'

guide me to over come this :)

Comment: UIActionSheet is deprecated why you do not try uialertcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is using KVO to try to access private properties of the UIActionSheet class. This is a bad idea, and may get your app rejected from the app store.

It's a bad idea because it relies on private implementation details of Apple's frameworks. In this case, it probably stopped working because Apple changed those private implementation details.

Comment: ok bro thanks ,because i am new to this and it is old code so i am confused ,now i am move with some other way except uiactionseet .

Answer (score 1):

`_buttons` does not comes in public Api. if you use this the apple does not agree your app. so Implemnt your code based on new concept, like this

```
UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"XXX "
                             message:@"pickAnyone"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction* first = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"abc"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             //Do some thing here
                             [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                         }];
UIAlertAction* second = [UIAlertAction
                          actionWithTitle:@"cde+"
                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                          {
                              [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                          }];
   UIAlertAction* third = [UIAlertAction
                       actionWithTitle:@"hhh"
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                       {
                           [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                       }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                     }];

[first setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
[second setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"cde+.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
[third setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"hhh"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];

[view addAction:first];
[view addAction:second];
[view addAction:third];     
[view addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: this is like alertcontroller bro thaks for your code and explanation ,now i am using tableview for it ,if its not fine then i will use your answer .

Comment: in here I used `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` , check once in ans bro

Comment: yes i understood bro but for me 20 images is there ,so i cant able to type that much ,so i prefered tableview .